# Define a controller that is specific to a directive in ngdocs

Tags: angularjs, gulp, ngdoc

I am using [ngdocs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation) to document my AngularJS application.  I have a controller in the API that is specific to the directive itself.  I have attempted to document this as `@module.directive:dirName.controller:ControllerName`, but this doesn't seem to tag this properly and the controller ends up being documented under a new module labeled as `module.directive:directiveName`.  Should I just document this under the `module`?  Anyone have any thoughts on the best way to do this?